# As independent contractor could an employeer require me to work a specific number of working hours?

Tags: contractors, hours

I have a Independent Contractor Agreement with a company in Texas (I'm outside US).

The agreement says:

> "It is understood that Contractor is an independent contractor in the performance of this Agreement and not an employee of Company. Nothing contained herein shall be construed to imply an employment, joint venture or principal and agent relationship between the parties; and neither party shall have any right, power or authority to create any obligation, expressed or implied, on behalf of the other."

In other paragraph:

> However, operating out of this Company location does not imply direct employment agreement and does not constitute regular full-time employment.. In the contract there is nothing about minimum hours or something like that.

The agreement says that there is a fixed amount of hours. I want to know if they have rights to make me work an amount of hours, or even pay me less if I don't work a determinated amount of hours.

One friend working for the same company was paid less money because supposedly worked less than the hours that they arbitrarily defined.

The only part of the contract related to this says:

> Contractor is expected to provide a minimum of 160 billable hours per month but is expected that Contractor will work more depending upon assigned project delivery deadlines.

^^^^ Is this part legal? When they make me perform a minimum of hours, will mean that I'm an employee of the company? They made me fill a timesheet in order to get pait.

Could they deduct from my payment because I worked less hours than stipulated in the contract (they wanted me to sign another agreement where it was explicitly stated, but I refused). One friend that worked in the company was paid half of his salary because of that.

Comment: I'm contracting directly

Comment: I want more to know that if is legal to have less pay if I don't work 160 hours at month, it wasn't stated in the contract

Comment: This is a contract question (legal) and is off-topic.

Comment: Really, it says you are to work 160 and if you don't work 160 you think they should still be required to pay you for 160?  Show them - don't sign the contract.

Comment: You are an independent contractor. You don't have an employer. The company that uses your services cannot give you any orders. They can politely tell you that they would like you to work a certain number of hours per week, and then you could consider their opinion and decide that this is a good idea, and that's how many hours you will work. And if you disagree with their suggestion, they might use a different contractor.

Comment: Since your contract _requires_ you to provide 160 billable hours per month, you clearly cannot work for anyone else, so I would argue with them that since you _have_ to provide 160 billable hours, it's up to them to use them, and their problem if they can't. @JoeStrazzere: I think it's a question of the company requiring the contract to be able to provide 160 working hours and not using them. Not about the contractor choosing to work one hour a month (which the contract explicitely says he cannot do).

Comment: If you don't want to work a minimum of 160, wouldn't a simple solution just to negotiate that number? E.g. agree to work a minimum of 80 billable hours, but more as required (that part is already written there)?

Comment: Find an attorney to hash this out because this is too complex for a general answer and hence off-topic here. Generally speaking a contractor decides his own hours. However, it's common for contracts to specify a retainer for a minimum of X hours a month reserved for the client. Typically those hours are charged in full to the company even if unused, or the contract could specify other fees or a higher base rate to compensate for a contractor's reserved time. This is all legally possible.

Answer (score 3):

Having an employee or contractor document their hours is normal enough. The specifics of the contract are up to the company, but it's entirely reasonable to pay less if an employee is logging less hours.

I can't answer from a legal perspective on here, but in general terms, yes, they can have anything in the contract that they want, you're not obligated to accept it, and you're allowed to try negotiating, but that rarely works out unless you have an exceptional skillset.

It's also fairly normal to try and determine if the employee or contractor is actually working the hours they log.

If you don't want to work on those terms, then your best option is not to take the job.